# yii2 - RBAC - is it shared between backend and frontend?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, rbac

I have just discovered and started using [Role Based Access control](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/security-authorization.md).

Since I am using an advanced template for yii2, I am wondering if roles and permissions are shared between backend and frontend tiers or if they are separated.

For example

```
<?php
namespace app\commands;

use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;

class RbacController extends Controller
{
    public function actionInit()
    {
        $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

        // add "createPost" permission
        $createPost = $auth->createPermission('createPost');
        $createPost->description = 'Create a post';
        $auth->add($createPost);

        // add "author" role and give this role the "createPost" permission
        $author = $auth->createRole('author');
        $auth->add($author);
        $auth->addChild($author, $createPost);

    }
}
```

would author and createpost be available for both backend and frontend?

thank you!

Comment: one the finest tutorial of Rbac in Yii2 www.freetuts.org/tutorial/view?id=6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RBAC componet are base on common part .. typically if they are base on DB you use  common models and  shared the related db table  ..

You can declare this element in component section of main.php in cofig area and if you do this in common dir this component si correctly shared between both the enviroment (frontend , backend) and eventually between all apps you distribute you projectc..

eg : common/config/main.php

```
      'components' => [
    .....
    'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        'cache' => 'cache',
          ....
    ],
```

this mean they could be naturally shared between frontend and backend ..

Comment: how to add permission, if it's shared with both module? means how to add module as well like controlloer/action, etc.

Comment: @AhmadAsjad   post a proper specific question .. (or comment me the link if you have already done)  well described  with a proper sample